# Some issue with Unit Testing on CI Gitlab

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, laravel-8

Goodday,

I have an issue with running my code through CI. When I run my code locally the test is fine.

So I have a Role Model (no pun intended)

and in my test i assign the role to a newly created test user.

```php
 // Assigning Role
        $role = Role::where('name','administrator')->first();
        $user->assignRole($role);
```

The assign Role is added through my User Model

```php
/**
     * Assigns Role to the User
     *
     * @param Role $role
     */
    public function assignRole(Role $role)
    {
        $this->roles()->save($role);
    }
```

When I run the Test locally it works like it was intended.

```
   PASS  Tests\Feature\UserTest
  ✓ user login
  ✓ users list allowed
  ✓ users list not allowed
  ✓ user creation
  ✓ user delete

  Tests:  6 passed
  Time:   7.05s
```

But when i am running it in my CI env. I get the following error message:

```
 ✓ basic test
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\UserTest
  ✓ user login
  ✓ users list allowed
  ✓ users list not allowed
  ⨯ user creation
  ✓ user delete
  ---
  • Tests\Feature\UserTest > user creation
   TypeError 
  Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::assignRole() must be an instance of App\Models\Role, null given, called in /builds/marcel43/backendapi/tests/Feature/UserTest.php on line 86
  at app/Models/User.php:73
     69▕      * Assigns Role to the User
     70▕      *
     71▕      * @param Role $role
     72▕      */
  ➜  73▕     public function assignRole(Role $role)
     74▕     {
     75▕         $this->roles()->save($role);
     76▕     }
     77▕
  1   tests/Feature/UserTest.php:86
      App\Models\User::assignRole()
  Tests:  1 failed, 5 passed
  Time:   0.97s
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mad an whoopsie on my database seeding, i created the seeder but did not add it to the database. That's why it could not find the role.